# Transform a edit router into a modal in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a screen where I render a DataTable through some filters.
When the table is generated I have a column called Ações (actions) where there is only one button which is a router-link that takes you to an edit form. But I would like this route to no longer exist, but when you click on this button it becomes a modal.

It only has two components, they are the GenericList and DataTable. GenericList is responsible for managing some things in my table. The DataTable is where these columns are being structured, including where I have my "Actions" column.

DataTable, where the router-link redirects to the "Edit" viewer:

```
<template>
    <div>
         ....
                        <td v-if="!noedit" data-editar class="align-middle">
                            <router-link data-cy="editar"
                                :to="item.href"
                                class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light text--black"
                                title="Editar">
                                <Edit3Icon size="20" alt="Editar" />
                            </router-link>
                        </td>
    </div>
</template>
```

View Edit, here I have my entire edit form ready (it's already filled out):

```
<template>
    <EditBase
        :loading="loading"
        :edicao="editing"
        @apagar="apagar"
        :nome="variavelInput"
        placeholder="Nova variável"
    >
        <form>
            <div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Tag *</label>
                        <b-form-input
                            type="text"
                            v-model="tagInput"
                        >
                        </b-form-input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Descrição: </label>
                        <b-form-input
                            type="text"
                            v-model="descricaoInput"
                        >
                        </b-form-input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="i_nome">Grupo *</label>
                        <vue-multi-select
                            class="multi-100"
                            v-model="grupoSelecionado"
                            search
                            historyButton
                            :selectOptions="gruposOpcoes"
                            data-cy="Grupos"
                            :btnLabel="() =>  grupoSelecionado[0] ? grupoSelecionado[0].nome : 'Selecione'"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="i_tipo">Tipo *</label>
                            <vue-multi-select
                                class="multi-100"
                                v-model="tipoVariavel"
                                historyButton
                                :options="{ multi: false, labelName: 'nome' }"
                                :selectOptions="tiposOpcoes"
                                :btnLabel="() => tipoVariavel[0] ? tipoVariavel[0] : 'Selecione'"
                            />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3" v-if="tipoVariavel[0] === 'Analógica' ">
                        <label class="mt-2">Unidade:</label>
                        <div>
                            <b-form-input
                                class="multi-100"
                                v-model="unidadeInput"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3" v-if="tipoVariavel[0] === 'Analógica' ">
                            <label class="mt-2">Taxa de amostragem *</label>
                                <b-form-input
                                    class="multi-100"
                                    type="number"
                                    v-model="taxaAmostragem"
                                />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2" v-if="tipoVariavel[0] === 'Analógica' ">
                            <label class="mt-2">Variação miníma *</label>
                                <b-form-input
                                    class="multi-100"
                                    type="number"
                                    v-model="varMin"
                                />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2" v-if="tipoVariavel[0] === 'Analógica' ">
                            <label class="mt-2">Valor mínimo:</label>
                                <b-form-input
                                    type="number"
                                    v-model="valorMin"
                                    min="0.000"
                                    max="0.100"
                                    step="0.001"
                                />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2" v-if="tipoVariavel[0] === 'Analógica' ">
                            <label class="mt-2">Valor máximo:</label>
                                <b-form-input
                                    type="number"
                                    v-model="valorMax"
                                    min="0.000"
                                    max="0.100"
                                    step="0.001"
                                />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3" v-if="tipoVariavel[0] === 'Digital' ">
                            <label class="mt-2">Estado on:</label>
                                <b-form-input
                                    class="multi-100"
                                    v-model="estadoOn"
                                />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3" v-if="tipoVariavel[0] === 'Digital' ">
                            <label class="mt-2">Estado off:</label>
                                <b-form-input
                                    class="multi-100"
                                    v-model="estadoOff"
                                />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3" v-if="tipoVariavel[0] === 'Digital' ">
                            <label class="mt-2">Taxa de amostragem *</label>
                                <b-form-input
                                    class="multi-100"
                                    type="number"
                                    v-model="taxaAmostragem"
                                />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3" v-if="tipoVariavel[0] === 'Digital' ">
                            <label class="mt-2">Variação miníma *</label>
                                <b-form-input
                                    class="multi-100"
                                    type="number"
                                    v-model="varMin"
                                />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                </div>
                <p class="small text-right">
                    Campos marcados com * são obrigatórios.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div v-if="editing" class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <button
                    class="btn btn-secondary align-self-center lg mr-2"
                    type="button"
                    data-cy="Cancelar"
                    @click="cancelar"
                >
                    Cancelar
                </button>
                <button
                    class="btn btn-danger align-self-center lg mr-auto"
                    type="button"
                    data-cy="Remover"
                    @click="remover"
                    :disabled="loading || saving || !editing"
                >
                    Remover
                </button>
                <button
                    class="btn btn-success align-self-center lg"
                    type="submit"
                    data-cy="Salvar"
                    :disabled="loading || saving || (!taxaAmostragem || varMin.length === 0 ? true : false || !grupoSelecionado[0] || !tipoVariavel[0] || !tagInput || !taxaAmostragem)"
                    @click="salvarEdicao"
                >
                    Salvar
                </button>
            </div>
            <div v-if="!editing" class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                <button
                    class="btn btn-success align-self-center lg"
                    type="submit"
                    data-cy="Salvar"
                    :disabled="loading || saving || !taxaAmostragem || !varMin || !grupoSelecionado[0] || !tagInput || !taxaAmostragem"
                    @click="adicionar"
                >
                    Adicionar
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </EditBase>
</template>

<script>
    import VueMultiSelect from "vue-multi-select";
    import "vue-multi-select/dist/lib/vue-multi-select.css";

    import { VariaveisService } from "../../services/variaveis";
    import { GruposService } from "../../services/grupos";

    import EditBase from "@/templates/EditBase";

    function options (timeout) {
        return {
            timeout: timeout || 2000,
            showProgressBar: true,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true
        };
    }

    export default {
        name: "AddEditVariavel",
        components: {
            EditBase,
            VueMultiSelect
        },

        data () {
            return {
                tagInput: "",

                gruposOpcoes: [],
                grupoSelecionado: [],

                tipoVariavel: [],
                tiposOpcoes: [],

                unidadeInput: "",
                variavelInput: "",
                descricaoInput: "",

                estadoOn: "",
                estadoOff: "",

                valorMin: null,
                valorMax: null,

                taxaAmostragem: null,
                varMin: null,

                variavel: [],

                errMsg: "",

                loading: false,
                editing: false,
                saving: false,
                deleting: false,

                gruposService: new GruposService(),
                variaveisService: new VariaveisService()
            };
        },

        async mounted () {
            this.getOptions();

            if (this.$route.params.id) return this.editar();
        },

        methods: {
            async getOptions () {
                this.gruposOpcoes = ((await this.gruposService.listGroups()) || []).map(g => ({
                    name: g.nome,
                    ...g
                }));
                this.tiposOpcoes = ["Analógica", "Digital"];
            },

            async adicionar () {
                try {
                    this.saving = true;

                    const payload = {
                        tag: this.tagInput,
                        descricao: this.descricaoInput,
                        id_grupo: this.grupoSelecionado.map(g => g.id),
                        tipo: this.tipoVariavel[0] === "Analógica" ? this.tipoVariavel[0] = "ANALOGICA" : "DIGITAL",
                        valor_minimo: this.valorMin,
                        valor_maximo: this.valorMax,
                        unidade: this.unidadeInput,
                        estado_on: this.estadoOn,
                        estado_off: this.estadoOff,
                        taxa_amostragem: this.taxaAmostragem,
                        variacao_minima: this.varMin
                    };

                    await this.variaveisService.addVariables(payload);

                    this.$router.replace("/variaveis");

                    this.$snotify.success("Variável adicionada", "Sucesso!");
                } catch (err) {
                    this.saving = false;

                    console.log(err);
                    this.$snotify.async("Aguarde...", () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        setTimeout(() => reject({
                            title: "Erro ao salvar",
                            config: options()
                        }));
                    }));
                }
            },

            async editar () {
                const id = this.$route.params.id;
                this.editing = !!id;

                const variavel = await this.variaveisService.listVariables();
                const idVariavel = variavel.find(v => v.id === +id);

                const grupo = await this.gruposService.listGroups();
                this.grupoSelecionado[0] = grupo.find(v => v.id === idVariavel.id_grupo);

                this.tagInput = idVariavel.tag;
                this.descricaoInput = idVariavel.descricao;

                this.taxaAmostragem = idVariavel.taxa_amostragem;
                this.varMin = idVariavel.variacao_minima;
                this.tipoVariavel = idVariavel.analogica ? ["Analógica"] : ["Digital"];

                this.valorMin = idVariavel.analogica ? idVariavel.analogica.valor_minimo : "";
                this.valorMax = idVariavel.analogica ? idVariavel.analogica.valor_maximo : "";
                this.unidadeInput = idVariavel.analogica ? idVariavel.analogica.unidade : "";

                this.estadoOn = idVariavel.digital ? idVariavel.digital.estado_on : "";
                this.estadoOff = idVariavel.digital ? idVariavel.digital.estado_off : "";
            },

            async salvarEdicao () {
                const id = this.$route.params.id;

                try {
                    this.saving = true;

                    const payload = {
                        id_grupo: this.grupoSelecionado[0].id,
                        tag: this.tagInput,
                        descricao: this.descricaoInput,

                        tipo: this.tipoVariavel[0] === "Analógica" ? this.tipoVariavel[0] = "ANALOGICA" : "DIGITAL",
                        taxa_amostragem: this.taxaAmostragem,
                        variacao_minima: this.varMin,

                        valor_minimo: this.valorMin,
                        valor_maximo: this.valorMax,
                        unidade: this.unidadeInput,

                        estado_on: this.estadoOn,
                        estado_off: this.estadoOff
                    };

                    await this.variaveisService.updateVariables(+id, payload);

                    this.$router.replace("/variaveis");

                    this.$snotify.success("Variável salva", "Sucesso!");
                } catch (err) {
                    this.saving = false;

                    console.log(err);
                    this.$snotify.async("Aguarde...", () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        setTimeout(() => reject({
                            title: "Erro ao salvar",
                            config: options()
                        }));
                    }));
                }
            },

            async cancelar () {
                this.$router.replace("/variaveis");
            },

            async apagar () {
                const id = this.$route.params.id;
                this.variaveis = await this.variaveisService.listVariables();

                const idx = this.variaveis.findIndex(c => c.id === +id);
                if (idx >= 0) {
                    this.variaveis.splice(idx, 1);
                }
            },

            async remover () {
                const id = this.$route.params.id;
                const variavel = await this.variaveisService.listVariables();
                const tagVar = variavel.find(v => v.id === +id && v.tag);

                this.deleting = true;

                const doDelete = () => this.variaveisService.deleteVariables(id)
                    .then(res => res.data.error ? Promise.reject(res.data.error) : res.data)
                    .catch(reason => {
                        if (reason.response && reason.response.data && reason.response.data.error) {
                            this.$swal.showValidationMessage("Falha ao excluir: " + (reason.response.data.error));

                            this.deleting = false;
                        }
                    });

                this.$swal
                    .fire({
                        title: "Você tem certeza?",
                        text: `A remoção de ${tagVar.tag} é irreversível`,
                        type: "warning",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        reverseButtons: true,
                        focusCancel: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: "#dc3545",
                        confirmButtonText: "Remover",
                        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
                        allowOutsideClick: () => !this.$swal.isLoading(),
                        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                        preConfirm: doDelete
                    })
                    .then((res) => {
                        if (res.value) {
                            this.$router.replace("/variaveis");

                            this.$snotify.success("Variável removida", "Sucesso!");
                            this.apagar(+id);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

I tried to add a "b-modal" directly to my Edit form, but it only opened inside the route. I would like it to open without redirecting me. Could someone help me with this? I really don't know how to proceed.